# Android webview javascript not working on API 18 or higher

Tags: javascript, android, webview, webviewclient

I want to display a website in `WebView` with manipulating some DOM element. I mean, I want to remove a special div element or replace it with something.
For this purpose I did something like this:
For replacing something I use [this](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_methods.asp) model

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World!";
```

I apply it for Android `WebView` like this:

```
public class WebClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {
             view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById(\"jumbotron-company\").innerHTML = \"\";");
    }
}
```

It is work on my device which API is 18 but not working on emulators or device which have API greater than 18

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What @Mattia said is correct. Use `evaluateJavascript` if possible. It has another advantage of being able to return the value of the result back from JavaScript.

But if you want an API-agnostic workaround, make sure that the code you evaluate using `loadUrl("javascript:...")` just doesn't produce any return value. An assignment returns the assigned value. In newer versions of WebView this value is used as contents for a new page that replaces the existing one.

You can make sure that the expression you are evaluating doesn't produce a return value in two ways:

- append `void(0);` statement at the end, e.g. `loadUrl("javascript:elt.innerHTML='Hello World!';void(0);");`
- run your code inside a function that doesn't return a value, e.g. `loadUrl("(function(){elt.innerHTML='Hello World!';})()");`

Answer (score 0):

From API level 19 you should use [evaluateJavascript](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#evaluateJavascript(java.lang.String,%20android.webkit.ValueCallback%3Cjava.lang.String%3E)):

> **public void evaluateJavascript (String script, ValueCallback resultCallback)**
>
> Added in API level 19 Asynchronously evaluates JavaScript in the
>   context of the currently displayed page. If non-null, |resultCallback|
>   will be invoked with any result returned from that execution. This
>   method must be called on the UI thread and the callback will be made
>   on the UI thread.

Please refer to migration guide for WebView in Android 4.4:
http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html