# JS ReferenceError on Android WebView for api level 15

Tags: android, webview, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm trying create a web app for Android using WebView. My cenary is very simple, **I have a index.html file with a button:**

```
<button id="connect-button" onclick="connect">Connect</button>
```

**and a simple (script) element:**

```
<script>
connect = function () {
   alert("Oi");
};
</script>
```

**On Android side I have an Activity to load this file on Webview**

```
WebView web;
web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview01);

//ProgressBar related to the xml
progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
progressBar.setMax(100);

web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
web.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebViewClient());
web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
web.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
web.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

For api level 19 or above everything works fine. But for api level 15 to 18 webview can't load my simple javascript method "connect".

I search a lot about problems with webview for api level bellow 19, but this is very simple test. Some one sometime make some thing similar to api 15 ?

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

For my case the problem is that aparently WebView for APIs lower than 19 you must put any code explicitly on "window" object.

So, when I change my java script to

```
<script>
window.connect = function () {
   window.alert("Oi");
};
</script>
```

everything works!

We have a lot of questions similar to this problem, if this not work for you check also:

- [Android webview javascript not working on API 18 or higher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30360889/android-webview-javascript-not-working-on-api-18-or-higher)
- [Android Javascript WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30521055/android-javascript-webview)
- [passing data to javascript in webview before android level 17 (4.2.2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25033852/passing-data-to-javascript-in-webview-before-android-level-17-4-2-2)
- [Android WebView loadUrl JavaScript not working API <=18 (but works in API >=19)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30913678/android-webview-loadurl-javascript-not-working-api-18-but-works-in-api-19)